# Problems with OpenLDAP-Replication

Tags: ubuntu, replication, openldap, ubuntu-14.04

we just set up a Ubuntu Server with OpenLDAP running.
We also have a second server, running Ubuntu as well.
Now i tried to set up the replication using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/servergu...er-replication

Problem is, when i want to add the provider file using

```
sudo ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f provider_sync.ldif
```

I get a error-message:

```
ldapadd: invalid format (line 5) entry: "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
```

Does anyone know where this problem comes from?

Here's the provider_sync.ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config

changetype: modify

add: olcDbIndex

olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq

-

add: olcDbIndex

olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config

changetype: modify

add: olcModuleLoad

olcModuleLoad: syncprov

-
add: olcModuleLoad

olcModuleLoad: accesslog


dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config

objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig

objectClass: olcHdbConfig

olcDatabase: {2}hdb

olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog

olcSuffix: cn=accesslog

olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=ex,dc=ample,dc=de

olcDbIndex: default eq

olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart


dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config

changetype: add

objectClass: olcOverlayConfig

objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig

olcOverlay: syncprov

olcSpNoPresent: TRUE

olcSpReloadHint: TRUE


dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config

changetype: add

objectClass: olcOverlayConfig

objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig

olcOverlay: syncprov

olcSpNoPresent: TRUE


dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config

objectClass: olcOverlayConfig

objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig

olcOverlay: accesslog

olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog

olcAccessLogOps: writes

olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE


olcAccessLogPurge: 07+00:00 01+00:00
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the content of `provider_sync.ldif`.

Comment: i've added it to the question.